# Programmatically create new view for WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift4, wkwebview

I'm trying to create a WKWebView on a button click.

All my views are created through code not through Storyboard or Xibs

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: Any) {        
        let myBlog = "https://apple.com/"
        let url = URL(string: myBlog)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: webView)   
    }

    /// More code to show elements on the view
```

When the IBAction event happens, Apples web site does appear but the view contents are in the background with the sendSubView toBack.

Is there a better way to open a URL in a WKWebView on a button click without navigation to a new view?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "Apples web site does appear but the view contents are in the background with the sendSubView toBack"?

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you show the code you are using to `show elements on the view`